# java game with tries options

Tags: java

I'm making a Guessing Game using Java and I need to add an option to count the number of guesses, but if the player gives the same answer multiple times, It will be count that as 1 try.

I don’t know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated :)

Here's my current script:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheNumber {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int count = 0;
            int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() *9);
            int guess = 0;

            System.out.printf("Guess the number from 1 - 10: ");

            while (guess != a) {
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
                count++;
                if (guess > a) {
                    System.out.printf("Lower!: ");
                } else if (guess < a) {
                    System.out.printf("Higher!: ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the number with "
                + count + " tries.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have both java and javascript tagged? They are completely different languages that do not work together

Comment: if the user enters `1 2 1 1 2 3` will it be counted as 5 guesses or 3 guesses?

Comment: java and javascript are completely unrelated - One is essentially a toy, designed for writing small pieces of code, and traditionally used and abused by inexperienced programmers.

The other is a scripting language for web browsers.

Comment: im sorry if i added the "javascript' tagged. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track all user's answers using a list so that you can iterate to the list if a similar answer exists before incrementing.

here it's pal

```
public class GuessTheNumber {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ;
    int count = 0;
    int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
    int guess = 0;

    System.out.printf("Guess the number from 1 - 10: ");

    while (guess != a) {
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        boolean isAnswered = false;
        for (Integer answer : answers) {
            if (guess == answer) {
                isAnswered = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isAnswered) {
            count++;
            answers.add(guess);
        }
        if (guess > a) {
            System.out.printf("Lower!: ");
        } else if (guess < a) {
            System.out.printf("Higher!: ");
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the number with "
            + count + " tries.");
      }
     }
```

Comment: can you type the code ? thank you so much in advance!